# How to give access to lists of objects which are part of an aggregate root?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, domain-driven-design

If I have an aggregate root which consists of say:

```
class Parent
{
    IEnumerable<Child> Children{ get; set; }
}
```

Children could contain any number of possible Child objects which are stored in the database.

What would be the best way of getting a total list of all Child objects to the application, so they can be presented in a UI allowing a user to attach/remove them from the Parent object?

Having a method in Parent such as

```
class Parent
{
    IEnumerable<Children> GetAllChildObjects { get; set; }
}
```

would surely corrupt the model with implementation details?

Would it be ok to have a domain service which calls the Parent repository and retrieves a full list. The facade to the application could then call the service directly, ensuring the Parent model stays "pure".

Update:

To give a bit more detail, i'm tidying up a system and trying to give it some structure.

A User can hold a number of WorkLocations. WorkLocations are pretty simple. The current system contains a webpage which displays user details including a full list of valid WorkLocations. Selecting locations from the list updates the User model with the new locations.

Currently, the UI pretty much hits the DB and pulls out the full list of WorkLocations. I need to pull this back into a more structured form.

Or, does this suggest that WorkLocation should not be in the User root as it currently is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I correct in thinking that you want all the WorkLocations from the database, regardless of what User they are attached to (if any)?

If so I would definitely go for the service approach, something like:

```
public interface IWorkLocationsService
{
    IEnumerable<WorkLocation> GetAllWorkLocations();
}
```

You might want WorkLocation to be immutable so that all changes to them go through User, though I suspect this isn't necessary here.

**Update:**

You could then add the following methods to `User`

```
// This gets filled from the db somehow.
private IList<WorkLocation> workLocations;

// IEnumerable so that all external additions and
// removals must go through dedicated methods.
public IEnumerable<WorkLocation> WorkLocations
{
    get { return workLocations; }
}

public void AddWorkLocation(WorkLocation locationToAdd)
{
    workLocations.Add(locationToAdd);
    // Do whatever else you need to, i.e. mark the item for saving.
}

public void RemoveWorkLocation(WorkLocation locationToRemove)
{
    workLocations.Remove(locationToRemove);
    // Do whatever else you need to, i.e. mark the item for saving.
}
```

Comment: Hi Joey, you're right. The system pulls the Work Locations in from another DB. The system I'm tidying up will never alter the details of Work Locations, but the end user needs to be able to attach/remove Work Locations to/from a User.

Comment: Ok, in that case it probably is worth making WorkLocation immutable, but only so that people using it realise its details are set elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you really must get the list of SonOfFoo for some reason, by using simple high level interfaces such as IEnumerable, you're not corrupting the model with implementation details.

Depending on what you need done, it would be better to avoid getting a list of SonOfFoo though, having Foo manage the work would be better.

Also depending on the amount of details SonOfFoo has, it would be a good idea to encapsulate it on an interface with the methods that the UI/Facade would need to use.

**Edit:**

From your description, the UI needs a list of the WorkLocations a user can work at (a IEnumarable would be a good choice), and then after the user selects the location and confirms it, the UI notifies the control the switch of the user with the selected location.

Comment: Hi Felipemaia, i've updated my original answer with a bit more detail.